# How to know onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt() method is called using javascript?

Tags: android, webview

I am implementing a native app which is works based on user location and I am using this method:

```
public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin,
            GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {         
        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
    }
```

I want to know if this method return true or false using JavaScript in the back-end. Can anyone help me to implement this?